# Solución de un If dentro de un For en VBA

Tags: visual-studio, excel, vba

***Buenos días***

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en VisualBasic for Applications (VBA), dentro de Excel, necesito un sistema de bucles que vaya recorriendo un determinado rango de filas y columnas, junto con una condición, que cuando haya un valor menor a 5 dentro de esas celdas, inserte una nueva fila resaltada con color rojo.

Estoy tratando de hacerlo con un For, desafortunadamente no logro conseguir que funcione correctamente. A continuación dejo el código elaborado hasta el momento, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

[image: Rangos de Excel]

```
Dim LimInferior As String
Dim LimSuperior As String

For LimInferior = Range("H2").value To LimInferior = Range("H5").value
 If LimInferior > 5 Then
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
Next LimInferior
End Sub
```

Comment: Tu código no hace nada de lo que quieres hacer. LAs variables de tipo `Range` se deben asociar a rangos, no a valores, así que Set LimInferior = Range("H2").value no tiene ningún sentido. Tampoco tiene sentido `For Each LimInferior In Range("H2").value`. Revisa bien cómo se construyen los bucles y prueba de nuevo

Comment: @Esei Buen día, he actualizado el código y creo que ya está mejor, pero aún no me funciona, espero puedas apoyarme, muchas gracias

Comment: que quiere decir no me funciona? tira un error? devuelve un valor equivocado? seguiste tu codigo? ese codigo sigue estando mal...

Comment: @gbianchi Que tal, con respuesta a tu comentario, me aparece un error al ejecutar el código 
"Error de compilación:
 No coinciden los tipos"

Entiendo que es por la sintaxis del código
Espero puedas apoyarme, muchas gracias
Saludos.

Comment: si LimInferior es un string, no lo podes comparar con un numero... yo no entiendo bien que tratas de hacer...

Comment: String es para textos. Los tipos de datos están en https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary